# EF 6 process query result (1mil records) in parallel

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am using EF 6 to query a database table where I have stored `animals`.

```
var results = _ctx.Animals.ToList();
```

Then I have few metohds that need to process certain types of animals.

```
 public void ProcessDogs(List<Animal> data)
 {
        var dogs = data.Where(t=> t.Category == "dog").ToList();
        // do some other work on the dogs
 }

 public void ProcessCats(List<Animal> data)
 {
        var cats = data.Where(t=> t.Category == "cat").ToList();
        // do some other work on the cats
 }

 public void ProcessCamels(List<Animal> data)
 {
        var camels = data.Where(t=> t.Category == "camel").ToList();
        // do some other work on the camels
 }
```

How can I optimally process all the records returned from my table in parallel? I cannot use `async-await`!

Comment: What has EF got to do this with, why no async await (just curious)

Comment: Also is the processing different for each animal

Comment: The process is more or less the same

Answer (score 0):

Simple. ONE thread reads the items, then queues them up into a queue for processing and multiple threads take them out and process them. One thread is plenty to handle the data reading, which - by the nature of networks - most likely is coming through one ethernet cable anyway.

Comment: The querying is pretty ok, I am mostly interested in the processing. That is slow.

Comment: Yeah, as I said. I have programs here using up 60 cores working like that. One queue, multiple worker threads. This is how IIS works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Parallel.ForEach`

```
var items = new [] {"cat", "dog", "camel"};

Parallel.ForEach(items, animal => {
   var list = data.Where(t=> t.Category == animal).ToList();
   // do rest
});
```

Comment: So inside the Parallel.ForEach do i call each method individually with the items as parameters? Mostly wondering about var list = `data`.Where(

Comment: Inside `Parallel.ForEach` is like you are inside every `Processxxx` method at the same time. I'm assuming your `Where` will return the same base type/interface for each animal, so you can just do your processing inside `Parallel.ForEach` or have a method `ProcessAnimals(List<Animal> animals)` and inside `Parallel.ForEach` do `ProcessAnimals(data.Where(t=> t.Category == animal))`

Comment: In your last sentence you mean: `ProcessAnimals(items` not `ProcessAnimals(data`?

Comment: No, it should be `ProcessAnimals(data.Where())`, you want to pass your filtered List to `ProcessAnimals` or you can do `ProcessAnimals(List<Animals> animals, string category)` and inside` `ForEach()` do `ProcessAnimals(data, animal);`

Comment: Got it. In your original answers above, there is no reference to `data.Where` that's why I was asking.